# Create a char count array for a String using java8 features

Tags: java, string, collections, java-stream

I wish to create a int[] of count for a particular String (comprising of only lowercase English Alphabets) using Java 8 stream API. Where arr[i] denotes the count of i-th character of English dictionary (e.g. arr[0] = count of 'a' in String str while arr[2] = count of 'c' in String str. This can be simply done by:

```
int[] arr = new int[26];
for(char c : str.toCharArray())
       arr[c-'a']++;
```

Or using IntSream in the 2nd way:

```
int[] arr = IntStream.range('a','z'+1).map(i -> (int)str.chars().filter(c -> c == i).count()).toArray();
```

But the problem with the second approach is that the String is traversed 26 times for each of the characters from 'a' to 'z'

Can you suggest a better way of achieving the same using java8-stream API?

PS: I know this can be done using Map but I need int[]

Comment: Your iterative approach is much better. Don't use streams. Keep what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use streams and keep the iterative approach, you could do it as well like this:

```
final int count[] = new int[26];
test.chars().forEach(c -> count[c-'a']++);
```

Comment: I found this working. Can you explain why is this not violation of the _"Effective final"_  clause of lambda functions?

Comment: As arrays are objects in java, the count array is de facto final; its reference is not changed during the iteration ie. it is not assigned to a new object. it stays final even if you change values (members) of an object.

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] r = str.chars()
             .boxed()
             .reduce(new int[26], 
                     (a, c) -> { ++a[c - 'a']; return a; }, 
                     (a1, a2) -> a1);
```

You know the former is simpler and better. My answer just proves it's feasible with the Stream API, and doesn't suggest that you should go with it. Personally, I would choose the map approach as the most intuitive one.

As pointed out by @Holger, `collect` is a better option here

```
str.chars()
   .map(c -> c - 'a')
   .collect(() -> new int[26], 
            (a, i)-> a[i]++, 
            (a1, a2) -> /* left as an exercise to the reader*/);
```

Comment: I would throw `.filter(i -> i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')` after `.chars()` just in case someone calls it with out-of-range characters in `str`, to avoid the potential out of bounds exception.

Comment: @DavidConrad I agree, but the OP seems to be confident with the `new int[26]`, maybe `str` is being validated before this

Comment: Modifying incoming arguments in a reduction function is an abuse of the API. Obviously, this would break with a parallel stream. This is a perfect use case for `collect`, which can even be done without boxing, `str.chars().map(c -> c - 'a').collect(() -> new int[26], (a,i)->a[i]++, (a1, a2) -> /* left as an exercise to the reader*/)`